# Unrecognized Selector in Swift/Objective-C/Applescript project

Tags: objective-c, swift, applescript, applescript-objc

I'm getting the following message when running this simple ASObjc program interfaced with Swift:

```
 *** -[ASMyObject foo:]: unrecognized selector sent to object <ASMyObject @0x60c000226fe0: OSAID(4) ComponentInstance(0x810000)>
```

The code works as expected if I remove the parameters from `foo`. I realize there must be something wrong with the way I'm creating `foo` with a parameter.

Here's the code, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32083098/3225395):

AppDelegate.swift

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    ASObjC.shared().myObject.foo(5)
}
```

ASMyObject.applescript

```
script ASMyObject
property parent : class "NSObject"

on foo(value)
    log value * 2
    return "Success!"
end foo

end script
```

ASObjC.h

```
@import Cocoa;
@import AppleScriptObjC;

@interface NSObject (MyObject)
    - (NSString *)foo:(int)value;
@end

@interface ASObjC : NSObject
    + (ASObjC *)shared;
    @property NSObject * MyObject;
@end
```

ASObjC.m

```
#import "ASObjC.h"

@implementation ASObjC

+ (void)initialize
{
    if (self == [ASObjC class]) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadAppleScriptObjectiveCScripts];
    }
}

+ (ASObjC *)shared
{
    static id shared = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        shared = [[ASObjC alloc] init];
    });

    return shared;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _MyObject = [NSClassFromString(@"ASMyObject") new];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "ASObjC.h"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add an underscore character to represent the colon in ObjC

```
on foo_(value)
    log value * 2
    return "Success!"
end foo
```

alternatively

```
on foo:value
    log value * 2
    return "Success!"
end foo
```

and in the category you have to declare the method to pass an object, an ObjC primitive does not work.

```
- (NSString *)foo:(NSNumber *)value;
```

To assign the value on the AppleScript side you have to coerce it

```
on foo:value
    log (value as integer) * 2
    return "Success!"
end foo
```

Comment: Hey @vadian! Cool to see you here. In both cases, I now get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error (code 1).

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much for the help and the original answer from a few years ago :)